# How can I hide specific duplicate rows in SSRS 2005?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Here's my problem: I have some some duplicate rows (rows with the same **ID**). What I want is to hide rows based on a specific's column value. The mentioned column is obviously not the ID column (it's the **Description** column).

I tried this on the Row Visibility (Expression):

```
=IIF (Fields!Incident_ID.Value = Previous(Fields!Incident_ID.Value)

AND

ReportItems!Description.Value <> "Incident Status Change to Work In Progress from Open", true, false)
```

So, I want to exclude the rows in which **Description** is not equal to 'Incident Status Change to Work In Progress from Open'.

The message that I get is:

> The Hidden expression for the table 'table 1' contains an error:
>   Object variable or With block variable not set.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you choosing to use `ReportItems!` for the Description value rather than `Fields!` ?  I am just asking for clarity.

Comment: I tried Fields! too, but I still get the exact same message:"The Hidden expression for the table 'table 1' contains an error: Object variable or With block variable not set." I didn't use ReportItems! for a specific reason instead of Fields!, I was just trying to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Any possiibility of any NULL values from the query result that you might be testing in this expression?  I think you'll receive this message in that case.  If this is the case then you'll also need to add a NULL value test(s) to your expression.

Comment: You mean that I should add a NULL value test to the Description Field?

Comment: Yes, probably it is a NULL value in the Description field for one or more of the rows.  The other field seems to be a key so it is seems VERY unlikely to have any NULLs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably getting that error because there are one or more rows in your query result that have a `NULL` value in the `Description` field.

You could test this theory by simplifying your expression to this:

```
=IIF(Fields!Incident_ID.Value = Previous(Fields!Incident_ID.Value), true, false)
```

just to see if you can run the report without error.

If that works, then you need to add a test for a `NULL` value as part of the larger condition test, to get back to the logic you intended.

Try this:

```
=IIF(Fields!Incident_ID.Value = Previous(Fields!Incident_ID.Value) AND IsNothing(Fields!Description.Value) = false AND Fields!Description.Value <> "Incident Status Change to Work In Progress from Open", true, false)
```

This should avoid the error by preventing the evaluation of the last part of the condition, when the `Description` has a `NULL` value.

Comment: David, when I use only the simplified expression the report works and gives the expected results. I tried your suggested addition to the code ( AND IsNothing(Fields!Description.Value) = false) but I get the message: The Hidden expression for the table 'table1' contains an error: [BC30451] Name 'falseANDFields' is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track just using ReportItems instead of Fields!

```
=IIF(Fields!Incident_ID.Value = Previous(Fields!Incident_ID.Value) AND Fields!Description.Value <> "Incident Status Change to Work In Progress from Open", true, false)
```

Comment: I tried this but I still get the exact same message:"The Hidden expression for the table 'table 1' contains an error: Object variable or With block variable not set."

Answer (score 0):

SSRS can be wonky sometimes. Try parenthesizing:

```
 =IIF(((Fields!Incident_ID.Value = Previous(Fields!Incident_ID.Value)) AND (IsNothing(Fields!Description.Value) = false) AND (Fields!Description.Value <> "Incident Status Change to Work In Progress from Open")), true, false)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your feedback was useful. It seems to solve the problem in a large scale, although the problem still exists for a few occasions. However, I can't find a kind of pattern for them.